# How to call a C Function from Lua with table type argument and table type return value?

Tags: c, lua

I want to implement a function with C language, this function should be called with an table argument, and it should return a table type value.

Normally we implement the function with C for lua like the code blow.But the library doesn't provide the luaL_checktable and lua_pushtable, what can we do?

```
static int average(lua_State *L)
{
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    double sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
            sum += lua_tonumber(L, i);
    }


    lua_pushnumber(L, sum / n);
    lua_pushnumber(L, sum);

    return 2;
}
```

Comment: [Programming in Lua: Table Manipulation](http://www.lua.org/pil/25.1.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use `luaL_checktype()`, it will return `LUA_TTABLE` in case of a table. Then use `lua_getfield()` or `lua_gettable()` or `lua_rawget()` to extract data from the table.

Edit:

To create a new table use `lua_newtable()` and the fill in the contents with `lua_setfield()` or `lua_rawset[i]()`. Don't forget to leave the table on the stack and return 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can I return a table value from C function?

Comment: Thank you so much, how can I leave the table on the stack?Should I use lua_settable(L,-3)?

Comment: You create it on the stack with ``lua_newtable()``, then manipulate it using the other functions and then just don't pop it. You should count elements on the stack to see what's left.